# when I need use copy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy

I try to understand when I need use `copy`? I thought that `copy` allocate new memory, but it doesn't. So, for example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"111", @"111"];
NSArray *array1 = array.copy;
NSMutableArray *array2 = array.copy;
NSMutableArray *array3 = array.mutableCopy;
NSArray *array4 = array.mutableCopy;
```

New memory allocated only for array3 and array4. So, I can do for array1 and array2 simply:

```
NSArray *array1 = array;
NSMutableArray *array2 = array;
```

When I can use copy, it is only make immutable array2, when it will be helpfull for me?

Comment: What I think you're missing is that `copy` increases the retain count for immutable objects, and actually makes a copy for mutable objects. Thus, under ARC it's less necessary than it once was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Cocoa, the `copy` method can be very smart: if an object is *immutable*, it could return itself without making a copy, because there is no point in copying objects that cannot be changed. In your example, `NSArray` is immutable, and `NSMutableArray` is mutable. That is why only mutable objects make actual copying. Of course all mutable copies must allocate new memory, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between:

```
NSArray *array1 = array.copy;
```

and

```
NSArray *array1 = array;
```

In the first case, the retain count of `array` is increased. In the second it is not. So if you ever release `array`, `array1` may become invalid in the second case, while it will still be valid in the first one.

*Exact consequences may depend of you using ARC or manual reference counting.*

Mutable objects will be copied no matter what, so that you can modify the original without affecting the copy. This is unnecessary for immutable objects, as they can't be modified.